# Keycloak 23.0.4 CORS configuration

Tags: cors, keycloak

I'm trying to log in via API from an Angular client on Keycloak on a different server but it keeps giving me the error "has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource ."

Searching online they say to set "+" to Web origin in Realm settings, but in my version that field is not there.
The closest thing I've found is Valid request URIs in clients>admin-cli>client details>advanced, but setting "+" in that field doesn't resolve the error.

What can I do?
Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out how to do it.
You had to enable `Standard flow` in clients>admin-cli>client details>settings to make the Web Origins field appear and then set *